# CSS for hyperlink in table header not applying?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for tables. I've now added a hyperlink in a table header but the CSS I added for it doesn't seem to apply even with !important. When I view in Dev Tools it looks as though it's applying the CSS for a basic  tag that is set in the Bootstrap file. I can't 100% confirm that because I'm using LESS and the Dev Tools just shows it coming from my compiled site.css file.

I copied the CSS that applies to the `thead > tr > th` and added the a.ess-table class from that.

```
.ess-table > thead > tr > th, 
.ess-table > tbody > tr > th, 
.ess-table > tfoot > tr > th { 
    background-color: #0078d2; 
    color: white; 
}

a.ess-table > thead > tr > th { 
    background-color: #0078d2;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

But this is what seems to be applied based on the Dev Tools.

```
a {
    color: #0078d2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<table class="table ess-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:80px;">
                <a href="#" id="approveAll">Approve</a>
            </th>
            <th style="width:80px;">
                <a href="#" id="denyAll">Deny</a>
            </th>
            <th>Shift Date</th>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Schedule</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>....</tbody>
<table>
```

Do I need to make a specific class to apply directly to the  tag in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` is on the wrong side of your css.  It should be:

```
.ess-table > thead > tr > th a {
```

instead of

```
a.ess-table > thead > tr > th {
```

```css
a {
    color: #0078d2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ess-table > thead > tr > th, 
.ess-table > tbody > tr > th, 
.ess-table > tfoot > tr > th { 
    background-color: #0078d2; 
    color: white; 
}

.ess-table > thead > tr > th a { 
    background-color: #0078d2;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table ess-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:80px;">
                <a href="#" id="approveAll">Approve</a>
            </th>
            <th style="width:80px;">
                <a href="#" id="denyAll">Deny</a>
            </th>
            <th>Shift Date</th>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th>Schedule</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>....</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

check out your rule:

```
a.ess-table > thead > tr > th { 
    background-color: #0078d2;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

You don't have anchors with the class `.ess-table`. You're probably looking for something like

```
.ess-table > thead > tr > th a { 
    background-color: #0078d2;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This selector **a.ess-table > thead > tr > th** means

```
<a class="ess-table"><thead><tr><th>...
```

That's why you need to put `<a>` under `<th>` tag. (suggested above)